# VB.NET Columns in Listbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox

Do any of you know how to make columns in a list box?
I have searched multiple sites, but none work. Please help!

Comment: Always start with either stackoverflow, msdn, or codeproject : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2377/Multi-Column-List-Box-in-C.  It is a c# project and I can help convert if you have issues.

Comment: And always use dataGridView if you need columns :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a ListBox, use ListView. It is very similar to the ListBox.

Using the Listview: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733652(v=vs.60).aspx

Also : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx

To add columns, use the details view

Answer (score 0):

I agree with loadingnow. I usually prefer the listview control. But, if you need the listbox, here is a link: [listbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn(v=vs.100).aspx) and then you can see how to add columns:

```
Me.listBox1.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"Item 1, column 1", "Item 2, column 1", "Item 3, column 1", "Item 4, column 1", "Item 5, column 1", "Item 1, column 2", "Item 2, column 2", "Item 3, column 2"})
```

Note you'll need to indicate that you want a multicolumn listbox:

```
Me.listBox1.MultiColumn = True
```

I hope it helps. Bye.